# ScrollView start scroll from right to left iOS

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I made UIView contains UIScrollerView that contains UITableView like that:

UIView
--UIScrollView
-----UITableView

UIScrollView.axis = .horizontal

width of UIScrollView is equal width the screen, 
widths of UIView and UITableView are equal. and greater than width of UIScrollView.

So, In the RTL language; How make UIScrollView start scroll from right -from end point of the width of UITableView to start of it- when start present UIViewController?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear enough to answer.

*Does the UIScrollView contains multiple UITableView?*

If you want your scrollview to scroll to the width of UITableView then use this code:

`scrollView.contentOffset.y = tableViewWidth`